# system update - failed to update libgranite5

Tags: updates, system

[image]
latest update has failed, anybody has any idea, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find out why you have the old Granite package in the first place. The current Granite package for eOS 6.x is 6.2, and you probably have some old apps installed by hand. Try to find out if there's a Flatpak version of that old app and use that one.

From my experience, you can get some old apps to run but only if they depend on `libgranite5` package and only that package. If the app needs a complete Granite stack you may end up with errors like you've described.